# Duplicate content issue due to Codeigniter controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter, duplicates

I am assisting with a Codeigniter website and don't have a background with it. It has been noted that there is duplicate page content. When I dug in, they are not actual pages, but controllers pointing to the same views. I attempted to set up 301 redirects in an .htaccess file in the root of the website, but it is not taking. In the application/config/routes.php, the following is noted:

```
    $route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
    $route['404_override'] = 'Home';
```

For example, there is a page http://mywebsite.com/weddings, and then http://mywebsite.com/Home/weddings was another controller that pointed to the same view. I attempted to add a 301 redirect from Home/weddings after removing the additional controller pointing to it, but now Home/weddings just redirects to the home page, as it is set up with the 404 override. I hope I have provided enough information for some assistance.

.htaccess file:

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


# add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# allow access to certain directories in webroot
RewriteCond $1 
!^(index\.php|robots\.txt|css/|lib/|js/|images/|^(.*)/images)

# gets rid of index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# page redirects
RedirectMatch 301 ^Home/weddings/$ /weddings
```

Home.php is as follows:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Admin_model');
    $this->load->model('Home_model');
    $this->load->helper('captcha');
    $this->load->library('recaptcha');
}

public function weddings()
    {
        $this->load->view('Template/Home/front_header');
        $this->load->view('Home/weddings');
        $this->load->view('Template/Home/front_footer');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not touch .htaccess. You have two options.

- Create a controller `Weddings.php` and in your `index.php` return a
  view for weddings page.
- The other option is to use `Home.php` controller and then add weddings method, the method should return the weddings page view. Your route should look like below:

```html
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
$route['404_override'] = 'Home';
$route['/weddings'] = 'home/weddings';
```

Hope this will help. Thank you

Edit

In your `Weddings.php` controller `constructor` check if there exist a "Home" and return 404 error. See below

```html
function __construct()
{
    parent::Controller();
    
    if($this->uri->uri_segment(1) == 'Home') {
      show_404();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kikuyu1. I have added what the wedding method is, and have that route set up, but both urls still show (ie. http://mywebsite.com/weddings and http://mywebsite.com/Home/weddings

Comment: I have edited Home.php as there isn't actually a Weddings.php. You can see what is there at the top. Everything was set up within this. I tried adding in the code provided within function __construct() but it caused an error. Should I place it somewhere else? I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Add `if($this->uri->uri_segment(1) == 'Home') { show_404(); }` below `parent::__construct();` and above `$this->load->model('Admin_model');`

Comment: You're saying that the file `/application/controllers.Weddings.php` does not exist?

Comment: That's correct. It was set up originally with /application/controllers/Home.php then all of the views were segmented under /Home, so there is a application/views/Home/weddings.php.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the error:An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined method CI_URI::uri_segment()

Filename: D:\home\site\wwwroot\application\controllers\Home.php

Comment: Use this instead  `if($this->uri->segment(1) == 'Home') { show_404(); }`